# Arduino 1.6.5 Error compiling - avr-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory Error compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-due

### **Situation:**

Arduino 1.6.5 have Error in compiling examples code "01.Basics/Blink"
[image: 01.Basics/Blink]

Verify the sketch without changing any coding, however shows following error
[image: 02. Error Compiling]

### **What i have tried BUT doesn't work:**

1) Go thru https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue

2) Followed all the steps

Following is the setting i use:
[image: 03. Setting]

Comment: That is strange, you have the Due selected on COM4, but set the board to Duemilanove. Can you change the board to Due and retry.